# Buildfire: How to customize the Side Menu

Tags: buildfire

how would I go about customizing the Side Menu for my application?

- Changing location from right to left.
- Adding custom sections like user profile section.

I cannot find an example Side Menu plugin in Github, so my guess is that it is unchangeable?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not an option in BuildFire. However, It is an upcoming feature due by next quarter. You should be able to manipulate it completely via the UI

Comment: Has this been released yet? I would like to remove some of the default links in the side menu

Comment: No. However, there is a hack to remove some of the default links in the side menu. Just go to the Settings > Language Settings > find the item you want to remove > Empty out the text... the system will know you dont want to use it. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the hack :)